# Publishing rdlc report to azure error..in mvc

Tags: azure, rdlc

When RDLC report run locally it works perfectly.But when I publish in azure then I got Error message as "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". For dlls

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
```

set  their property: copy local = true.But the error persists..

Comment: I believe Copy Local should be False anyway. Just make sure that the Path is correct and it points to the actual location of the file being referenced.

Comment: I am rendering the rdlc to pdf.. Is their any problem?? @Oceans